# How to bind dataform in XAML

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, dataform

```
....
xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MyRecipe.ViewModels">

<navigation:Page.Resources>
    <viewmodel:RecipeViewModel x:Key="RecipeViewModel" />
</navigation:Page.Resources>

<toolkit:DataForm x:Name="form" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Recipes}" Width="500" Height="600" />
```

In the viewmodel:

```
public EntitySet<Recipe> Recipes
{
    get { return _recipes; }
    set
    {
        if (_recipes != value)
        {
            _recipes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Recipes");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to bind the dataform to the Recipes entityset.  The dataform is not showing any fields or any indication that it is bound.  What's wrong?

Comment: Where is the data context getting set?

Comment: Not sure if I understand.  The domain context is set in the constructor of the RecipeViewModel.

Comment: Are you sure that in _recipes are some items?

Comment: Yes, because when the dataform is bound in C# it works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
<toolkit:DataForm x:Name="form" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
DataContext="{StaticResource RecipeViewModel}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Recipes}" Width="500" Height="600" />
```

Had to add the DataContext line.

Comment: Ya, but I guess I didn't realize it had to be set and I didn't realize how to set it.  Next time post the answer! :)